# ipython3 iptest3 error

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I am running Mac OSX 10.7.5. I removed Python 2.7 and installed Python 3.3. I installed ipython and when I run iptest3 I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/iptest3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ipython==0.13.1', 'console_scripts', 'iptest3')()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2308, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py3.3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2014, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>

from .config.loader import Config
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/config/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>

from .application import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/config/application.py", line 31, in <module>

from IPython.config.configurable import SingletonConfigurable
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/config/configurable.py", line 26, in <module>

from .loader import Config
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/config/loader.py", line 27, in <module>

from IPython.utils.path import filefind, get_ipython_dir
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/utils/path.py", line 25, in <module>

from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/utils/process.py", line 27, in <module>

from ._process_posix import _find_cmd, system, getoutput, arg_split
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 22, in <module>


from IPython.external import pexpect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py3.3.egg/IPython/external/pexpect/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>

import pexpect
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pexpect-2.4-py3.3.egg/pexpect.py", line 82

except ImportError, e:

                  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

pexpect is not compatible with Python 3.  You need to install [pexpect-u](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect-u).

Answer (score 0):

Seem like a pexpect issue to me. 
Can you import pexpect in normal python3.3 shell ?

Also

- I'm not sure the ipython .egg works on python3.
- I don't think you **need** to remove 2.7 to use 3.3